# Upgrade and Rooting Motorola Xoom Paths

Tags: rooting, updates, motorola-xoom

I have a UK Motorola Xoom, Wifi only version. It's currently running 3.0.1 and is rooted.

I'd really like to upgrade to 3.2 and stay rooted. What's the best path to take with this?

I can't download the official "over the air" update, because that clashes with the rooting process I have performed (I assume) as that bricks the device. I have been using it for a while and have many settings and apps in place. I assume there is no way I can do an in place upgrade and keep everything as it is?

I assume I will have to use something like Titanium Backup, then find a pre-rooted 3.2 image and flash that on, then restore my apps and settings? Can anyone confirm if this is correct or not?

Finally, if that is true, can anyone point me to such an image for my model tab?

Answer (score 1):

You could try CyanogenMod 9 (there's a release candidate now):

CM9 has support for the [Motorola Xoom (wifi)](http://get.cm/?device=wingray), and the [Motorola Xoom (Verizon)](http://get.cm/?device=stingray) at this point.

Here's CyanogenMod's [update guide](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/wiki/Motorola_Xoom_%28Wi-Fi%29%3a_Full_Update_Guide) from their wiki for the Xoom.

You have to backup your device in advance, of course (using TitaniumBackup for example).

Comment: I cannot find CyanogenMod any longer. The site seems down :(

Comment: Alas, CyanogenMod has shut down. You may find the info in the mirrors:
https://www.reddit.com/r/cyanogenmod/comments/5kfo0m/the_cyanogenmod_archives_full_downloads/ (see Browsable pages)

Comment: alternatively, have a look at the successor project site:
http://lineageos.org/community/

Answer (score 1):

The path I have taken is to install [Wingray](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1675986). This is a build of CM9 (Android 4.x ICS) specifically for the Xoom table. So I got to go strait to ICS and keep root. Just had to re-flash with this image!

Comment: Just a bit of nitpick: Wingray is a codename of Xoom MZ604. You installed SGT7 for Wingray.